# In proof that a continuous function defined on an interval takes an absolute maximum value

Tags: real-analysis

In the Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis , proof of p.39, 23 theorem I do not understand some statement.

> Theorem. A continuous function $f$  defined on an interval $[a.b]$ takes on absolute minimum and absolute maximum values.

***Proof.*** First, for each $x \in [a,b]$, define $V_x := \{f(t) : t \in [a,x]\}$.

Let $M := \sup V_b$. Since the values of a continuous function defined on an interval $[a,b]$ form a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, such $M$ exists. Consider the set $X:= \{ x\in[a,b] : \sup V_x < M \}$

Case 1. $f(a) = M$. Then $f$ takes on a maximum at $a$ and the theorem is proved.

Case 2. $f(a) < M$. Then $X \neq \varnothing$ and we can consider the least upper bound of $X$, say $c$. If $f(c) < M$, we choose $\epsilon <0 $ with $\epsilon < M - f(c)$. By continuity at $c$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|t-c| < \delta$ implies $|f(t) -f(c)| < \epsilon$. Thus $\sup V_c <M$. **If $c<b$ this implies there exist points $t$ to the right of $c$ at which $\sup V_t <M$**, **contrary to the fact that $c$ is an upper bound of such points**. Therefore, $c=b$, which implies that.. (Omitted). QED.

**Q.** Why the bold statement ( existence of such $t$ ) is true?

Since $ \sup V_c < M := \sup V_b$, there exists $f(t_0) \in V_b$ such that $\sup V_c := \sup \{t(t) : t\in [a,c] \} < f(t_0)$. If $a \le t_0 \le c$, then $f(t_0) \le \sup V_c$, which is contradiction. So $c< t_0 \le b$. Note that $\sup V_{t_0} \le \sup V_b =: M$. A point that I stuck is "if $\sup V_{t_0} < \sup V_b =: M$ then we are done, but there is a possibility of $\sup V_{t_0} = M$" Is there any other route to show existence of such $t$ in the bold statement ( satisfying the strict inequality $\sup V_t < M$ )?   Can anyone helps?

Comment: I suppose that you meant that $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c<b$ then define $\delta':=b-c>0$. Fixing $\varepsilon<M-f(c)$, there exists $\delta''>0$ such that $|f(t)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $t\in[a,b]$ and $|t-c|<\delta''$.

So let's define $\delta:=\min(\delta',\delta'')>0$. There exists a whole continuum of real $t>c$ satisfying $0<|t-c|=t-c<\delta$, just pick from the interval $(c,c+\delta)\subset[c,b]$. Let's fix such a $t$, call it $t_0$.

I know $f(t_0)<\epsilon+f(c)<M$ and I actually know this holds if $t_0$ is replaced with any $c\le t<t_0$. It follows from $\sup V_c<M$ and the above inequality that $\sup V_{t_0}<M$ since $\sup\{f(x):c\le x\le t_0\}\le\epsilon+f(c)<M$.

Very similar reasoning is used to deduce $\sup V_c<M$.

Comment: Thanks. :) You mean, $\sup V_{t_0} = \sup \{ \sup V_c , \sup \{f(x) : c \le x \le t_0 \}\} < M $?  I'm still not convinced this strict inequality. And why you invove the $\delta ' := b-c > 0$ in the definition of $\delta$? To guarantee that $ c < t_0 < b$ ?

Comment: @Plantation Yes to both. While it is true there are points to the right of $c$ which are $\delta’’$-close to $c$, we need points that are also in $[a,b]$ for $f$ to be defined. This is one reason why the case $c<b$ is different from the case $c=b$, as in the latter case there is no space to the right of $c$ still contained in $[a,b]$. The main point is that $\delta’$ is positive: if $c=b$, $\delta’$ and $\delta$ will be equal to zero which is not helpful

Comment: Thank you very much !~

Comment: @Plantation You're welcome